# PHP: Data from cURL, HTML Scan

Tags: php, html, html-content-extraction

How can i scan a html page, for text within a certain div?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to do this would be to use [Simple HTML DOM parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm)

```
// Create a DOM object from a URL
$html = file_get_html('http://www.google.com/');    

// Find all <div> which attribute id=foo
$ret = $html->find('div[id=foo]');
```

Answer (score 0):

`preg_match()` to match the substring you want or use dom/xml.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this using the `DOMDocument` class.

Usage is pretty straight-forward:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML(file_get_contents($url));

// Example:
$dom->getElementById('foo');
```

Documentation is [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php).

An example of real world usage can be found [here](http://github.com/koraktor/steam-condenser/blob/7b1357b415af0f478f2cf6830e56e9f4ad19247a/php/lib/steam/community/SteamId.php#L229).

Answer (score 0):

You could use build in functionality as suggested by others or you could try the Simple HTML DOM Parser is implemented as a simple PHP class and a few helper functions. It supports CSS selector style screen scraping (such as in jQuery), can handle invalid HTML, and even provides a familiar interface to manipulate a DOM.

It's worth to check it out at http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/